# Initialized a struct variable to NULL, but it isn't null when called

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

I have to make a graph datatype with functions according to some specific guidelines.

I have to have a function that initializes an empty graph. In this function, I set the first vertex to NULL. Just testing this, I run my num_vertices method and I get a segmentation fault. It should return 0.

After my own debugging, I've learned that somehow after calling the init function on a new graph, calling the num_vertices functions somehow passes a vertex that isn't NULL, even though the init function set it to NULL. Therefore my num_vertices method is running through all the memory allocated for my graph until it hits the seg fault.

Why is this happening, how can I set it to NULL so that my num_vertices works?

My graph structure (required to do it similar to this):

```
typedef struct Edge Edge;
typedef struct Vertex Vertex;
typedef struct Graph Graph;

struct Graph {
    Vertex *vertex;
};

struct Vertex {
    /* use a tree to store vertices */
    Vertex *left;
    Vertex *right;

    char *name;
    Edge *edge; /* the edge between this vertex and its root */
};

struct Edge {
    unsigned int cost;
};
```

My init_graph() and num_vertices():

```
void init_graph(Graph *graph) {
    graph = (Graph *)malloc(sizeof(Graph));
    graph->vertex = NULL;
}

int num_vertices(Graph graph) {
    return count_vertices(graph.vertex);
}

int count_vertices(Vertex *vertex) {
    int count = 0;
    if (vertex != NULL) {
        count += count_vertices(vertex->left);
        count++;
        count += count_vertices(vertex->right);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Finally, the code I'm using to test this that gets a seg fault:

```
int main() {
    Graph graph;

    init_graph(&graph); /* initialize new graph */

    assert(num_vertices(graph) == 0); /* seg fault here */

    printf("It all worked!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why are you *first* allocating memory to `graph->vertex` and **then** overwriting that set pointer with `NULL`?!

Comment: `(Graph** graph) and *graph = malloc(...)` or alternatively, return a Graph*

Comment: How do these fragments compile? `int num_vertices(Graph graph)` should be `int num_vertices(struct Graph graph)`. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: @WeatherVane the casts in `malloc` - I suspect this is **C++**..

Comment: It compiles in C++ :))

Comment: In `main` with the C tag `Graph graph;` is a syntax error. Where are foreign languages mentioned?

Comment: So, I suppose @RetiredNinja 's comment is the answer, isn't it?

Comment: Graph was allocated locally in main and passed to `init_graph`, so both the mallocs are unnecessary.  Just set vertex to NULL.  Alternatively, since the OP seems to really be using C++, retag the question and use a constructor :^)

Comment: Forgive me, I'm a beginner to C and pointers.I assure you I'm using C, not C++, and this compiles. Actually using C90 compiler restrictions. The struct definition and graph functions are in a separate file from the main. If both mallocs are unnecessary, can I simply set the vertex to NULL in the init?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You allocated a `Graph` pass its address to a function which manipulates it through a pointer in which you store dynamically allocated chunk of memory, thus you are not chaging anything in the original variable. This is non-sense. Just init the structure, like this:

```
void init_graph(Graph *graph) {
    graph->vertex = (Vertex *)malloc(sizeof(Vertex));
    graph->vertex = NULL;
}
```

Note that your code is not valid C except if you typedef-ed Graph.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this fixed it! I was under the assumption that I had to dynamically allocate memory for the Graph structure itself as well as its internal components. Why is this not the case? Also, the structs are typedef-ed I just ommitted that from my OP; I've since added it.

Comment: This is just a memory leak.

Comment: @shplaz It is not the case because writing `Graph graph` already allocates memory for a Graph object! Read about variables and pointers.